# IIS Rule Help - Redirection

Tags: iis

I need your help to create a Redirection rule in IIS.

You have the following scenario:

When a user types [www.mipagina.com](http://www.mipagina.com), he is redirected to [www.miotrapagina.com](http://www.miotrapagina.com), except if he enters some routes such as [www.mipagina.com/MyApp1](http://www.mipagina.com/MyApp1), in this case he should not be redirected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can learn some regular expressions and then help yourself, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mipagina.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.miotrapagina.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```